# Why can't daemon attach to php session?

Tags: php, session, nginx

I have a simple php daemon running as root that is supposed to interact with the nginx-served frontend by sharing a session of known id. However, when I access the session created by the frontend, daemon fails:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_id('s9vk3f64p13hg9iour09a3jqs3'); // <- frontend session
//session_id('uhddmla8uv7tkltnrkb1v9ek70'); // <- non-frontend session

session_start();
echo session_id() . "\n";
session_write_close();
```

Error:

```
Warning: session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/run) in /var/www/sess.php on line 1
```

I have permission `777` on `/run`. The daemon can however attach to sessions it has created itself. The only difference is the permissions:

```
root:/var/www# ls -l /run/sess*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 961 Aug 21 13:42 /run/sess_s9vk3f64p13hg9iour09a3jqs3
-rw------- 1 root     root       0 Aug 21 13:48 /run/sess_uhddmla8uv7tkltnrkb1v9ek70
```

I've verified the session is not otherwise locked:

```
root:/var/www# lsof /run/sess_s9vk3f64p13hg9iour09a3jqs3
```

Why can't `root` open/write a session that `www-data` has created and owns?

**UPDATE**

This is the `strace` output of the script, cut the the relevant section:

```
open("/run/sess_s9vk3f64p13hg9iour09a3jqs3", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_LARGEFILE|O_NOFOLLOW, 0600) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=961, ...}) = 0
getuid32()                              = 0
geteuid32()                             = 0
close(3)                                = 0

write(1, "sess: s9vk3f64p13hg9iour09a3jqs3"..., 33) = 33
open("/run/sess_s9vk3f64p13hg9iour09a3jqs3", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_LARGEFILE|O_NOFOLLOW, 0600) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0777, st_size=961, ...}) = 0
getuid32()                              = 0
geteuid32()                             = 0
close(3)                                = 0

write(1, "\nWarning: session_write_close():"..., 181) = 181
close(2)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
munmap(0xb6f08000, 4096)                = 0
close(0)                                = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be a PHP issue introduced with 5.4: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69582&thanks=3

**UPDATE**

As a workaround you can do something like this to impersonate the user that has created the session file:

```
$pre_session_uid = posix_getuid();
posix_seteuid(posix_getpwnam(SESSION_ADMIN_USER)['uid']);
```